# Evaluating the end time of a period of time

Tags: python

I am working on a simple code able to evaluate the end time of a period of time, given as a number of minutes (it could be arbitrarily large). The start time is given as a pair of hours (0..23) and minutes (0..59). The result has to be printed to the console.

**For example, if an event starts at 12:17 and lasts 59 minutes, it will end at 13:16.**

So far I tried below code and finding difficult to get hours calculation please help.

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
mins = (mins + dura)%60
hour = **** Please help this calculation ****
print(hour, ":", mins, sep='')
#expected output is 13:16 (ex: given hour = 12 , mins = 17 , dura = 59 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
    mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
    dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
    dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(hour, mins)) + timedelta(minutes=dura)
    print(dt.time().strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Output: `13:16`

Answer (score 4):

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
time_hour = (hour + dura//60 + (mins+ dura%60)//60)%24
time_min = (mins+ dura%60)%60
print("It will end at " + str(time_hour) + ":" + str(time_min))
```

It will end at `13:16`

Answer (score 1):

I understand this has been answered. However I ran across this exact problem in some practice work for learning python. The end result just wanted the time in HH:mm format.

```
#given hour = 12 , mins = 17 , dura = 59

hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
hour = (hour + dura//60 + (mins+ dura%60)//60)%24
mins = (mins+ dura%60)%60
print(hour,":",mins,sep="")

13:16
```

The last line was requested like this. I understand this was largely explained and answered, but I saw a difference in syntax and wanted to share my results.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
mins = mins + dura # find a total of all minutes
hour = hour + mins // 60 # find a number of hours hidden in minutes and update the hour
mins = mins % 60 # correct minutes to fall in the (0..59) range
hour = hour % 24 # correct hours to fall in the (0..23) range
print(hour, ":", mins, sep='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))

print ("Event ending time: ",(hour + (mins + dura)//60)%24, ":", (mins + dura%60)%60, sep="")# Write your code here.
```

At the level the question is asked, it requires us to find the answer with one line of code. So, This is what i came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is if you want pure math

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))

hour = hour +int((mins+dura)/60)
mins = (mins + dura)%60
while(hour/24>=1):
    hour=hour-24
  
print(hour, ":", mins, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
hr=((((hour*60+mins)+dura)//60)%24)
min=((hour*60+mins)+dura)%60 
print(hr,min,sep=":")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))


hours = (hour + (mins+dura)//60)%24
minutes = (mins+dura)%60
print(hours, ":",minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this exercise in a course and managed to solve it this way:

I know the code it's too large, was my first try solving a problem in Python, but I know it can be written shorter.

```
# Data input
start_hour = int(input('Enter start hour: '))
start_minute = int(input('Enter start minute: '))
event_duration = int(input('Enter event duration (min): '))

# Adding the minutes
total_minutes = (start_minute + event_duration)

# Calculating the hours
calc_hours = total_minutes / 60

# Calculating the residual for minutes
min_residual = int(total_minutes % 60)

# Calculating the residual for hours
hrs_residual = int((calc_hours + start_hour) % 24)

# Printing the answer
print('\nThe event end at:')
print(hrs_residual,':',min_residual)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
```

#here we will get the minutes part by adding all the minutes and get the excess minutes.. the excess minutes will be the minutes part..

```
minutePart = (mins + dura)%60
```

#here we will get the hours part by 1- adding all the minutes and get the int part of the result adding to the given minutes in the inputs then get the excess hours after dividing by 24 ..

```
hourPart = (((mins + dura)//60)+hour)%24
print("event will end at " , hourPart , ":" ,minutePart , sep="" )
```

I've tested the code with all the possibilities and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
hh = int(input("Start Hour: "))

mm = int(input("Start Minute: "))

add_min = int(input("Additional Minute: "))

endhh = hh + (add_min // 60)  

endmm = mm + (add_min % 60)

endhh += endmm // 60

endmm = endmm % 60

endhh = endhh % 24  

print('{}:{}'.format(endhh, endmm))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: An example of what Adriaan must be thinking of is why the solution needs the   6th and 7th lines. As slick as integer division and modulo are, they need to be applied again in case the additional minutes push the minutes past 60.

Answer (score 0):

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))

#Total minutes i.e.. minute the event started to event duration
mins = dura + mins
print(mins)

#Minutes to hour conversion
mins_tohour = mins % 60
print(mins_tohour)

#Hour calculation i.e how much hours are elapsed since the beginning of the event. 
#//60 to get a round value and dividing by 24 hours to be within the 24 hour range.
hours = (hour + mins // 60) %24
print(hours)
print(hours, mins_tohour, sep =":" )
```